# client.GetGuild() returns null. Discord.NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio, discord.net

built a bot using DISCORD.NET, but ran into a very silly error, for some reason, GetGuild returns null, my guild id is exactly right.

`SocketGuild guild = client.GetGuild(guildID);`

I'm pretty new to c#, so maybe it can be mistake in code, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I guess that "GetGuild" is Async...if so, then you must " await client.GetGuild(guildID);".

Comment: didn't work.
`'SocketGuild' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'SocketGuild' could be found`

Comment: Are you setting your DiscordSocketClient correctly? Are doing it like this: [link](https://discordnet.dev/guides/getting_started/first-bot.html)

Comment: Yes, I have almost the same

Comment: Sory...cannot help you more with just that code.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced similar problems in the past when requesting something through the client by simply passing an ID. Usually I circumvent this by looping the Guilds collection on the client

```
foreach (var guild in client.Guilds) {
   if (guild.Id == guildID) {
      // This is the guild
   }
}
```

From here, you can either work with it within the loop, or assign it to a previously stated variable, or even extract this to a method with ID parameter

```
SocketGuild guild = getGuild(guildID);

private SocketGuild getGuild(ulong id) {
   foreach (var guild in client.Guilds) {
      if (guild.Id == id) {
         return guild;
      }
   }
}
```

Unfortunately I am unable to explain why this is sometimes the case

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have much code to refer to, I assume this is an asynchronous event.

If so, before you call the event, do the following

```
var guild = client.GetGuild(guildID);
```

then, pass it thru the event args, and on the receiving side, put it as:

```
SocketGuild guild
```

It should be able to detect it before calling it.

This may be wrong due to the shortcode provided above.

Comment: I'm not sure what the event being async or not has to do with calling `GetGuild`. Async methods can call non async code just fine.