# Discord.Net SocketClient.GetGuild(id) returns null

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I've got a Problem with Discord.Net which I can't solve on my own or with Google.
I'm also pretty much still a beginner, so there's that.
I want to call a function which every 5 minutes does a thing and if a certain criterion is met, it should post a message to a specific channel on a specific discord server.
Because it should not be triggered by a Command, I don't have the Context Variable.

```
public async Task MainAsync()
{
    using var services = ConfigureServices();

    Console.WriteLine("Ready for takeoff...");
    var client = services.GetRequiredService<DiscordSocketClient>();

    client.Log += Log;
    services.GetRequiredService<CommandService>().Log += Log;

    // Get the bot token from the Config.json file.
    JObject config = Functions.GetConfig();
    string token = config["token"].Value<string>();

    // Log in to Discord and start the bot.
    await client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
    await client.StartAsync();

    await services.GetRequiredService<CommandHandlingService>().InitializeAsync();

    //This is the problematic part
    var ServerID = Convert.ToUInt64(config["serverid"]?.Value<string>().ToLower());
    var ChannelID = Convert.ToUInt64(config["channelid"]?.Value<string>().ToLower());
    var Guild = client.GetGuild(ServerID); //The ID is filled and correct but the function always returns null
    var Channel = Guild.GetTextChannel(ChannelID);
    await CheckForChange(Channel);

    // Run the bot forever.
    await Task.Delay(-1);
}
```

I don't know what the problem is. It also seems that client. Guilds are empty, even tho the bot already joined two servers.

I tried giving the function CheckForChange() different parameters, like only the SocketClient, the Channel, the IDs etc. Shouldn't really make a difference (I guess) but GetGuild(ID) always returns null.
Also, in the Discord Dev Portal, all Privileged Gateway Intents are enabled.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73305630/client-getguild-returns-null-discord-net Probably should help

Comment: Yeah, ive seen that post but it doesnt help me. As far as i can tell im not using a async event here and the method cant be called with await. But thanks for the fast answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to retrieve the guild immediately after starting the client (`StartAsync`). There needs to be some delay provided for the client to connect to all available guilds before it's able to retrieve any guild or guild data. The `Ready` event is fired once it's connected to all guilds. Ideally you should subscribe to the `Ready` event and place your logic in there.

Note that the ready event can be triggered multiple time due to the bot needing to sometimes identify on a reconnect, so you should unsubscribe from the event within the event so you logic is only triggered once.

```cs
//make these fields so they can be accessed outside of main (in Ready)
private readonly DiscordSocketClient _client; 
private readonly JObject _config;

public async Task MainAsync()
{
    using var services = ConfigureServices();

    Console.WriteLine("Ready for takeoff...");
    _client = services.GetRequiredService<DiscordSocketClient>();

    _client.Log += Log;
    services.GetRequiredService<CommandService>().Log += Log;

    // Get the bot token from the Config.json file.
    _config = Functions.GetConfig();
    string token = _config["token"].Value<string>();

    // Log in to Discord and start the bot.
    await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
    await _client.StartAsync();

    _client.Ready += Ready;  //subscribe to the ready event

    await services.GetRequiredService<CommandHandlingService>().InitializeAsync();

    // Run the bot forever.
    await Task.Delay(-1);
}

private async Task Ready()
{
    _client.Ready -= Ready; //unsubscribe from the ready event

    //move problematic part here (should no longer be problematic)
    var ServerID = Convert.ToUInt64(_config["serverid"]?.Value<string>().ToLower());
    var ChannelID = Convert.ToUInt64(_config["channelid"]?.Value<string>().ToLower());
    var Guild = _client.GetGuild(ServerID);
    var Channel = Guild.GetTextChannel(ChannelID);

    await CheckForChange(Channel);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked great. And it does make sense ^^ Just didnt think about that