# Discord.NET Bot Fails to Retrieve Guild Roles and Channels on Test Server Compared to Local

Tags: c#, .net, discord, discord.net

I am developing a Discord bot using Discord.NET.WebSocket Locally, it functions perfectly, retrieving all necessary guild information such as roles and text channels. However, when deployed to a test server, it fails to retrieve the guild roles and specific text channel information.

Here is the core part of the bot service where the issue occurs:

```cs
DiscordSocketClient _client = new DiscordSocketClient(new DiscordSocketConfig
{
    GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.Guilds | GatewayIntents.GuildMembers
});

public async Task<IInviteMetadata> GenerateDiscordInvite()
{
    try
    {
        var guild = _client.GetGuild(Convert.ToUInt64(_discordServerSettings.ClientId));

        throw new DiscordBotException(
            $"guild id: {guild.Id}," +
            $"guild name: {guild.Name}," +
            $"guild roles: {string.Join(", ", guild.Roles.Select(role => role.Name))}," +
            $"guild channels: {guild.GetTextChannel(Convert.ToUInt64(_discordServerSettings.ChannelId))?.Name}," +
            $"client login state: {_client?.LoginState}," +
            $"client user name: {_client?.CurrentUser?.Username}," +
            $"guild is admin: {guild.CurrentUser?.GuildPermissions.Administrator}," +
            $"guild user name: {guild.CurrentUser?.Username}");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw a new DiscordBotException("Failed to generate invite: " + e.Message, e);
    }
}
```

Additionally, here is the `StartAsync` method that initializes the `DiscordSocketClient`:

```cs
public async Task StartAsync()
{
    await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, _discordBotSettings.Token);
    await _client.StartAsync();
}
```

And the hosted service that invokes `StartAsync`:

```cs
public class BotHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IDiscordBotService _botService;

    public BotHostedService(IDiscordBotService botService)
    {
        _botService = botService;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _botService.StartAsync();
    }
}
```

**Example Responses:**

- **Local Environment Response:**

```
guild id: 123456789123456789,
guild name: TestGuild,
guild roles: Role1, Role2, Role3,
guild channels: General,
client login state: LoggedIn,
client user name: TestBot,
guild is admin: True,
guild user name: TestBot
```

- **Test Server Response:**

```
guild id: 123456789123456789,
guild name: TestGuild,
guild roles: ,
guild channels: ,
client login state: LoggedIn,
client user name: TestBot,
guild is admin: False,
guild user name:
```

**Problem:**

The bot, when deployed on a test server, does not retrieve `GuildRoles` and `GuildChannels`, which is critical for its functionality. This issue does not occur in the local development environment. Both environments use the same Discord bot account with identical permissions.

**Question:**

What could cause the Discord bot to fail in retrieving `GuildRoles`, `GuildChannels` and guild current user on the test server, despite working as expected locally? Are there specific environmental or configuration aspects I might be overlooking?

I logged discord bot and server configs: `clientId`, `token`, `clientSecret` - they are identical on local and testing. Also, Discord server and bot settings in Discord are identical (since I use the same discord server and bot on both envs).

Any guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While I was unable to recreate your problem to verify, it has some similarity with this question [client.GetGuild() returns null. Discord.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73305630/client-getguild-returns-null-discord-net/76620709#76620709) - I believe my response was helpful for the asker, and could be worth a try for you (I'm assuming it's cache related and how client.GetGuild() works)